# error on Intent.putExtra AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am using asy task for doing loading proccess while the service is supposed to take care about the connection. 
I am getting some error on the line:

```
serviceIntent.putExtra("receiver",new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
```

when I am using AsyncTask and service to do the connection.
my code is for AsyncTask is:

```
 private class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver{
public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

@Override
   protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
  //  if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
        int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
     //   mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
     //   if (progress == 100) {
       //     mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }



  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.putExtra("url", "www.google.com");

            new DownloadReceiver(new Handler());
            serviceIntent.putExtra("receiver",new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
    serviceIntent.setAction("connection.DownloadService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

so what can be the problem?

Comment: post the stack trace that the error is giving. but also can you elaborate on what it is you are trying to achieve? You've provided very little context for what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Why are you trying to start a `Service` to perform a download from the worker thread of an `AsyncTask`? It doesn't make sense. Either perform the download in `doInBackground()` or simply start the `Service` from your main `Activity` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( this error == compile time error){
`DownloadReceiver` class should implements the   Parcelable interface 
}
else{
```

I think you are getting an error since you are creating the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object inside the  `doInBackground()` method which executed in another thread than the UI one, then some where in your application you are accessing the `UI Thread` using that `Handler` object 
. Note : To do that correctly you SHOULD create the `Handler` in `UI Thread`. what a good place to do that for your case .

```
onPostExecute
```

or put it as a instance variable . and pass it in the constructor;

}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Intent modifications are right, then move  your `Intent` code
from the AsyncTask's doInBackground method into the onPostExecute function.

You can't modify any Views from inside doInBackground, you must do it in one of the callback functions that are guaranteed to be run on the event dispatch thread.